# Take parsed XML and put into a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, parsing

My challenge is to take an XML feed, parse it, then put parsed data into a javascript array which is then read by jquery to output on a page. The jquery side is written and works with a static array. I also can parse the XML. But can a parsed XML feed populate an array such that:

```
var text = new Array();  
text [1] = "first item parsed"  
text [2] = "second item parsed"  
etc.
```

Comment: Yeah, XML can be parsed an put into an array. You'll need more specifics to get a better answer.

Comment: give us the XML code, so we can see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can simply loop through the "items"

use this to sequentially add "items" to a blank array

```
var text = new Array();
$.each(xml_items, function(i,item) {
    text.push(item);
}
```